# Camunda Process Modification after process instance has completed

Tags: camunda

Can a COMPLETED process be **modified** using cockpit in enterprise version of Camunda such that it is brought back to its last stage (stage just before completion)?
Note that community version is being evaluated using REST API and condition is that the processInstanceId should not change.

The reason for asking this question is after Camunda has successfully finished processing as per work-flow and now is responding to the caller using REST API and suddenly there is a network outage, so in this special case, Camunda and the caller's respository shall be out of sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you can get to this is the `POST /process-definition/{id}/restart` API. However, it does not restore the process instance with the same id.

Links:

- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/reference/rest/process-definition/post-restart-process-instance-sync/
- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/user-guide/process-engine/process-instance-restart

Comment: Thanks @thorben. The links were useful. If its not possible to MODIFY the process instance after its completion, I mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Correct. Process instance modification only applies to running instances.